# Continuity of derivative in Inverse Function theorem in Deimling's book

Tags: continuity, inverse-function-theorem

[image]

I am having a question on the following proof of the Inverse function Theorem in Deimling's book.
It is stated that if  $G$ is continuously differentiable, then $G_{|U}^{-1}$ is also continuosly differentable. However in the proof Demling proceeds to show that $T=G_{|U}^{-1}$ is differentiable (locally) and  $T'y = G'(Ty)^{-1}$ holds. However it doesn't explain that $T'(\cdot)$ i.e. $G'(\cdot)^{-1}$ is continuos?

**So my question: how does continuity of $T'(\cdot)$ follows from continuity of $G'(\cdot)?$**

Because he proceeds to prove for higher degrees of smoothnes, by induction. Induction however is not a proper thing to do if he hasn't proven the case $m=1$ in his notations. If it's obvious from the circled equality that in addition to being

P.S. I am aware of my question here [my question her](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712477/frechet-differentiability-of-implicit-function-in-banach-spaces) and my current question has the same principle in core I think. Namely that the inversion map $A \to A^{-1}$ is smooth. In particular continuous which would probably explain what Deimling has in mind.

How do I prove that indeed the inversion map is smooth? And doe this , like I suspect, resolve my problem?

Comment: smoothness of the inversion map has been discussed several times on the site. Inversion is actually an analytic map as well. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3662806/568204) for some ideas; I’ll leave it to you to fill in the necessary estimates for power series (or look them up in a text, for example, Henri Cartan’s differential calculus). Or just search for the Neumann series (really just a geometric series).

Comment: Thank you! I just found this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145497/inversion-is-smooth  usefull too.
So basically analytical function in Banach space. I suppose you can differentiate it infinitely many times from then on.

Here I need only the continuity of $Inv$ and its even Lipchitz continous since
$||Inv(A+H)-Inv(A)||\leq ||H||.\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}||A^{-1}||^{k+1}||H||^{k-1}=c||H||.$ (Provided  $A$ is invertiable and $||A-H|| < 1/||A^{-1}||.$)
And now $T'(\cdot) = G'(\cdot)^{-1} = Inv \circ G'(\cdot)$ and both $Inv$ and $G'(\cdot)$ are continuous. So indeed...:) Makes sense..

Comment: See also Loomis and Sternberg (freely available online; they have a small section on Banach algebras which is relevant)